# Cleaning Webscrape Text for FastText in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-cleaning, corpus, fasttext

**BLUF**: How can I clean up large corpora with issues of words being lumped together (like "quarterbackpa" or "passquarterback")?

**Background**:
I am working on my Capstone project for my Data Science degree, and the project entails scraping sports articles on NFL QBs to analyze their contents in an attempt to determine the presence of implicit bias based on race.  I've scraped over 11,000 articles using trafilatura and combined them into two corpora: white and nonwhite.  Each contains roughly half of those articles.  Then, I preprocess the corpora (stemming, removing stopwords, storing in a CSV with each line representing a sentence and each cell a word in the sentence).

When I run FastText against the corpora and look for nearest_neighbors, I just get a list of closest words that are nothing more than the original word with minor deviations.  For example:

`model.nearest_neighbors('smart')`

`[('smartidea', 0.36853086948394775), ('vsmart', 0.326141357421875), ('intelligent', 0.3181183338165283), ('smartpo', 0.27458563446998596), ('smartqb', 0.2703150510787964)]`

This exists for all results; there's a lot of dirty data in my corpora.  The question is: how do I apply a solution?

**Solutions I've tried**:

- Created a function to test if a word exists in pydictionary.  If not, prompt for input as to what the word should be and store the result in a custom dictionary that the code also checks against.  This solution works but takes far too long (I stayed up for 6 hours to work on one chunk of 100,000 characters - and I have 114 more to go for just the white corpora).
- Edited the previous solution to just record the location of the word that didn't exist in the dictionary so I could go back and change it manually.  This also took forever; I set it to run and came back a day later only to find 2 chunks finished.

I don't need specific code, just general processes/packages that can assist with this.  If there's nothing, please let me know that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Often, if you have enough data, you can ignore such concerns. Typos & other glitches are just a little random noise, which has negligible effect on the final vectors for the common words of most interest. (And indeed, by using FastText, even the char n-gram substrings of typos likely still acquire mildly-helpful subword vectors from the same surrounding usage contexts.)

To the extent such 'junk' words might clutter the more salient results from the more-frequent 'head' of the words distribution, it often makes sense to just ignore words that occur below a certain frequency – as they tend to have weaker vectors (from fewer training examples) even when they're not pure typo/junk tokens.

The training process already does this, to an extent, via the default `min_count=5` setting – discarding very-rare words to improve the quality & training-time for remaining words.

The results reported from `most_similar()` can also be limited, via the `restrict_vocab` optional parameter, to only consider the first N known-words (which in usual practice are the N most-frequent words).

So it's easy, & often wise, to:

- discard very-rare words, as having low info-content or being potential junk/noise, even before `FastText` training, per the default `min_count=5`.
- ignore additional rarer words, that were still useful in training, when reporting results – because they tend to have rougher vectors & murkier meanings than the strongly-modeled more-frequent words, & thus can cloud the stronger-results among more-frequent words.

If you feel your data is thin enough that you *need* to correct the problems, as you've already discovered, that can be a very tedious process. If you have a reliable preexisting lexicon for the domain – as you've used `pydictionary` – you can use that to nominate candidates-for-correction, and perhaps then a growing cache of decisions that either the word is still OK, or what it should be corrected-to.

(If your simple check to notate unknown-words is taking a day to work through a subset of your mere 11,000 articles, there is likely some gross inefficiency in your tokenization/search - perhaps overuse of regular expressions.)

The general area of automatic-spelling-correction has many potential approaches, but also tradeoffs where something that works as an occasional suggestion for review might destroy new domain-specific language if applied automatically, indiscriminately.

Peter Norvig's article "[How to Write a Spelling Corrector](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)" is a classic intro to a statistics-based approach that may provide some useful ideas.

Most generally, keep in mind that the 'long tail' of unique errors may be large large – but each individually, & even all of the idiosyncratic errors altogether, may not be that important. In a large training process, where there's plenty of other 'signal' from the rest of the data, any amount of random noise may not hurt much. So getting 2x as much 'dirty' data, & ignoring the long-tail or rarest words/errors, often better than meticulously correcting a smaller set of texts.

Even in any manual reviews/corrections, I'd recommend working from most-frequent tokens to least, rather than in pure front-to-back sequence. That is, review batches of the most-frequent words in your corpus that are not in your known-list of words – to see if they're concerns that need correcting – rather than *every* anomalous word from front to back.

Finally, as it seems you may be attempting to quantify bias via word-vectors, note that if using the `most_similar()` method for tasks like analogy-solving, it *won't* respond with any of the input words, even if the calculated 'target-point' is closest to them. (See the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741677/130288) for more details about how this has sometimes confused writeups about word-vector biases, as well as how sometimes supplying raw vectors instead can work-around.)