# When applying word2vec, should I standardize the cosine values within each year, when comparing them across years?

Tags: word2vec, word-embedding, cosine-similarity

I'm a researcher, and I'm trying to apply NPL to understand the temporal changes of the meaning of some words.
So far I have obtained the trained embeddings (word2vec, sgn) of several years with identical parameters in the training.
For example, if I want to test the change of cosine similarity of word A and word B over 5 years, should I just compute them and plot the cosine values?

The reason I'm asking this is that I found the overall cosine values (mean of all possible pairs within that year) differ across the 5 years. **For example, 1990:0.21, 1991:0.19, 1992:0.31, 1993:0.22, 1994:0.31. Does it mean in some years, all words are more similar to each other than other years??

Base on my limited understanding, I think the vectors are odds in logistic functions, so they shouldn't be significantly affected by the size of the corpus? Is it necessary for me to standardize the cosine values (of all pairs within each year) so I can compare the relative ranking change across years? Or just trust the raw cosine values and compare them across years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should not think of cosine-similarities as an *absolute* measure that'd be comparable between models. That is, you should not think of "0.7" cosine-similarity as anything like "70%" similar, and choose some arbitrary "70%" threshold to be used across models.

Instead, it's only a measure within a single model's induced space - with its effective 'scale' affected by all the parameters & the training data.

One small exercise that may help illustrate this: with the exact same data, train a 100d model, then a 200d model. Then look at some word pairs, or words alongside their nearest-neighbors ranked by cosine-similarity.

With enough training/data, generally the same highly-related words will be nearest-neighbors of each other. But the effective ranges of cosine-similarity values will be very different. If you chose a specific threshold in one model as meaning, "close enough to feed some other analysis", the same threshold would *not* be sufficient in the other. Every model is its own world, induced by the training data & parameters, as well as some sources of explicit or implicit randomness during training. (Several parts of the word2vec algorithm use random sampling, but also any efficient multi-threaded training will encounter arbitray differences in training-order via host OS thread-scheduling vagaries.)

If your parameters are identical, & the corpora very-alike in every measurable internal proportion, these effects might be minimized, but never eliminated.

For example, even if people's intended word meanings were perfectly identical, one year's training data might include more discussion of 'war' or 'politics' or some medical-topic, than another. In that case, the iterative, interleaved tug-of-war in training updates will mean words from that overrepresented domain have far more push-pull influence on the final model word positions – essentially warping subregions of the final space for *finer* distinctions some places, and thus *coarser distinctions in the less-updated zones.

That is, you shouldn't expect any global-per-model scaling factor (as you've implied might apply) to correct for any model-to-model differences. The influences of different data & training runs are far more subtle, and might affect different 'neighborhoods' of words differently.

Instead, when comparing different models, a more stable grounds for comparison is *relative rankings* or *relative-proportions* of words with respect to their closeness-to-others. Did words move into, or out of, each others' top-N neighbors? Did A move more closely to B than C did to D? etc.

Even there, you might want to be careful about differences in the full vocabulary: if A & B were each others' closest neighbors year 1, but 5 other words squeeze between them in year 2, did any word's meaning *really* change? Or might it simply be because those other words weren't even suitably represented in year 1 to receive any position, or previously had somewhat 'noisier' positions nearby? (As words get rarer their positions from run to run will be more idiosyncratic, based on their few usage examples, and the influences of those other sources of run-to-run 'noise'.)

Limiting all such analyses to very-well-represented words will minimize misinterpreting noise-in-the-models as something meaningful. Re-running models more than once, either with same parameters or slightly-different ones, or slightly-different training data subsets, and seeing which comparisons hold up across such changes, may also help determine which observed changes are robust, versus methodological artifacts such as jitter from run-to-run, or other sampling effects.

A few previous answers on similar questions about comparing word-vectors across different source corpora may have other useful ideas or caveats for you:

[how calculate distance between 2 node2vec model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084092/how-calculate-distance-between-2-node2vec-model/59095246#59095246)

[Word embeddings for the same word from two different texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392103/word-embeddings-for-the-same-word-from-two-different-texts/57400356#57400356)

[How to compare cosine similarities across three pretrained models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61736874/how-to-compare-cosine-similarities-across-three-pretrained-models/61741677#61741677)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations! It's amazing that you explained it in laymen's words. I found it very useful.